# Pulling a specific line of byte text from a textfile

Tags: java

I have a program that takes a username and a password and stores it on text files. Before storing the password I encrypt the data and store the password and the generated encryption key on separate text files. I have it so multiple "accounts" can be made and the next users information goes on the next line of the file. This works fine until I want to pull the encrypted byte password and key from a certain line and decrypt it when using FileInputStream. I know which line the each password and key belongs to by searching though the text file that stores the usernames and recording the line it exists on. So I guess my question is, how can pull the byte data from a file from a specific line to use with decrypting, and is there a better way to go about this whole set-up. Below is my code from the class that should pull the bytes, decrypt the password using the key, and then verify that the password ented on the login screen is the same as the password entered when the account was made.

```
Login() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{

  //Check to make sure a username has been entered.

  if (!name.contains("[a-zA-Z0-9]") && name.length() > 0 ){

  //Find which line the user's data is stored on:

        try{
            int LineCount = 0;
            String line = "";

            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/user_names.txt"));
             while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 LineCount ++;

            int posFound = line.indexOf(name);

            if (posFound > - 1) {
                System.out.println("Search word found at position " + posFound + " on line " + LineCount);


 //What do I do here to read my key and password from their text files from the line found above.

//The following code works when there is only one entry on each line of the text files.


            FileInputStream keyFis = new FileInputStream("resources/password_keys.txt");
            byte[] encKey = new byte[keyFis.available()];
            keyFis.read(encKey);
            keyFis.close();

            Key keyFromFile = new SecretKeySpec(encKey, "DES");


            FileInputStream encryptedTextFis = new FileInputStream("resources/user_data.txt");
            byte[] encText = new byte[encryptedTextFis.available()];
            encryptedTextFis.read(encText);
            encryptedTextFis.close();


            Cipher decrypter = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyFromFile);
            byte[] decryptedText = decrypter.doFinal(encText);



            System.out.println("Decrypted Text: " + new String(decryptedText));


                      }else{

                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("The password you entered has not been created."),
                 "Missing account", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
             }

             bReader.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
        }

  }else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Please enter a valid username."),
"No Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

  }

}
```

As you can tell I am rather new to this sort of stuff. I have tried to read the lines using BufferedReader but it will write it to a string which removes the byte data I need to use to decrypt. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you would have to read every line in the file until you reach the line number you are interested in - in Java files get read in streams, so you always have to go sequentially through them. This is the most inefficient way.

**Edit:** If you can guarantee every line has the same amount of characters, you could do the above by using the [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) which has a `skip()` method, you can feed it the number of lines multiplied by the number of characters per line and get to where you want to go.

You could also read your file once and cache it in memory using a List or Map. This is assuming you don't expect it to get to large. However, at that point you would have to deal with the problem of keeping the in memory version and the file version synchronized.

Really the proper solution would be to use an LDAP data base such as [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) or any kind of relational database, to store your data in - assuming that makes sense with the rest of the system architecture.

Comment: I have been struggling with a way I can read a text file line by line using a FileInputStream so I can keep keep the byte[]s instead of reading a line with a BufferedReader that will make it a string and unusable. I am trying to keep it rather simple so I am shying away from using a database which would be the more proper way.

Comment: @user2805420 hmmm... well if you are down to bytes reading lines does not really work, but you could get a String and the call the getBytes() method. This might be problematic though, depending on how your text file is written, so you could also take the bytes when you write them and encode them in Base64 and then decode on reading. Base64 allows you to store byte data as a string.